# skip a navigation menu problem in liferay?

Tags: menu, navigation, liferay

I have been working in a web site which contains a lot of pages. These pages works perfeclty. I ´ve created 3 pages and I inserted them in their respective navigation menus. I posted the pages from staging to live mode. But here appears the problem. When I´m trying to go to the new pages in live mode always redirect me to staging one. I dont know how to repair it. If I try to do that beeing a guest is imposible cause Liferay obligate me to log in to access into staging. 
the redirect on these pages is in this fomat: ... web/intranet-staging/... (redirect me always to this url and to staging)
How can I skip it?  Thanks

Comment: What is you Liferay Portal version?

Comment: 7.1 GA1 version

Comment: Are you sure your pages are public? Can you reproduce that on a clean instance? If you can, then open a bug report. Otherwise it may be something that you have configured or installed that causes this. It's hard to say without knowing all the details.

Comment: How did you insert them in their menu? Is it Liferay generated URL or you create those links manually?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier i added them in the menu manually

Comment: Are you using remote staging (whetter on the same server on different one) or local staging?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier i am using local staging